# Assuming that A is the matrix of a linear operator F in S find the matrix B of F in R

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Assuming that A is the matrix of a linear operator F in S find the matrix B of F in R

A is:
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}

S = {(1,1), (1,2)}

R = {(1,0), (0,1)}

---

F(1,1) = (1,1) + (1,2)

F(1,2) = (1,1) + 2(1,2)

F(2,3) = 2(1,1) + 3(0,1)

F(3,5) = 3(1,0) + 5(0,1)

So B=

\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\3&5\end{bmatrix}

---

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In order to compute $B$, you must compute $F(1,0)$ and $F(0,1)$. Since$$(1,0)=2(1,1)-(1,2),$$you know that\begin{align}F(1,0)&=2F(1,1)-F(1,2)\\&=2\bigl((1,1)+(1,2)\bigr)-\bigl((1,1)+2(1,2)\bigr)\\&=(1,1).\end{align}So, $B$ will be like $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&?\\1&?\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Now, you can compute the second column by the same process.

Comment: (1,0)=2(1,1)−(2,1) is that one correct? Or I am just stupid

Comment: @JamesSmith I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: F(1,0)=2[(1,1)+(1,2))−((1,1)+2(1,2)]=(1,1).

Emm.. I don't really understand that part :(

And one more question if I can. What was wrong with my solution as I want to know what mistake I made. Thanks

Comment: @JamesSmith I've edited my answer (again). Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes it is :) But shouldn't it be (-1,1) at the end of F(1,0)=... ?

Comment: @JamesSmith No, because $2\times(1+1)-(1+2\times1)=1$, not $-1$.

Comment: So the result is 

\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix} ?
It's a bit weird

Comment: But, yes, that's the correct answer.

Comment: I tried to do a few more examples and I am not sure if I am getting correct result. Would be great if you could check this one for me:
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\2&1&0\\3&0&1\end{bmatrix}



S = {(0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0)}
||||
R = {(1,1,0), (1,1,1), (0,1,1)}

I get 
\begin{bmatrix}3&6&5\\3&3&1\\3&4&1\end{bmatrix}

Comment: @JamesSmith This is another question. Please post it as such. But I can tell you right away that you are wrong.

Comment: Okey I thought that will be better to stay in one post.